# Tag Wiki Privileges - why does my tag wiki need to be peer approved when I have the same privilege?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I have the required rep to edit tag wikis (2006 at the time of writing) and it shows as such in my profile, yet whenever I'm editing and adding info to a tag, the banner at the top says - "You do not have tag wiki edit privileges".

Is this intentional behaviour ? Even a user with the approval to edit tag wikis needs to get it approved by others?

[image: Tag Wiki Screenshot]

Comment: Good question. Sounds to me like it might be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure how the tag wiki privileges work, to be honest, but based on the rep listings (for a beta site):

- [At 1500 rep](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) you gain the ability to approve tag wiki edits
- [At 4000 rep](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) you gain "trusted user" status and can edit all tag wikis
- Any registered user can submit a tag wiki edit but it must be approved by someone with sufficient rep (or possibly a Mod?)

Technically speaking, then, it appears that 1500 rep is *not* actually enough to edit wikis without approval. This does seem a bit confusing, though, since you could seemingly approve your own edit based on the by-the-letter description of the 1500 rep priv. I don't know if it actually works out that way, though...